# Taking information from an txt file with XML tags and making a new file with the information

Tags: python, xml, file, python-3.x, tags

So I wanted to play around with files a bit, and decided to delve into XML tags. But, I am at a loss. I have no idea where to start and all the places I look either confuse me or I am having issues with them.

Right now I have literally the bare bones of my code. I am not sure how to interact with the XML tags in the file to write info and take data from them.

```
def XMLData(fileName):
    #read file.
    rFile = open(fileName, "r").read()
    #make new file for summarizing data.
    nFile = input("")
    #write to new file.
    wFile = open(nFile, "w")


    #Stuff to write goes here.


    #write to new file the data from read file.
    wFile.write(readFile)
    #close file.
    wFile.close
```

For example I have a group of tags for a football team.

```
<team>
<name> Denver Broncos </name>
<players>
<player>
<jno> 50 </jno>
<fname> Zaire </fname>
<lname> Anderson </lname>
<height> 5-11 </height>
<weight> 220 </weight>
<age> 24 </age>
<position> ILB </position>
<school> Nebraska </school>
</player>
</players>
</team>
```

What I would like to accomplish is writing to a new file some info along with utilizing the data from the XML tags like so:

```
There are {} players on the team. #number of <player> tags
Zaire Anderson, ILB, wears J50. He is 5 foot 11 inches tall, and weighs 220 pounds. He is 24 years old. He went to Nebraska. #Info on the <player>
```

Could anyone point me to a good resource to use or give me some help to get me going? I'm not asking anyone to write any code for me, just wanting so help to get me out of my hole i'm in.

Comment: take a look at `lxml` tutorial.

Comment: is this question still active?